# Rails parse upload file "\xDE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I try parse upload *.txt file and get some import DB information. But before save it I try get tring in utf-8 format. When I do that I get error:

```
"\xDE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

First file characters

```
Import data \xDE\xE4\xE5
```

Before parse code

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "iconv"

class HandlerController < ApplicationController

    def add_report
        utf8_format = "UTF-8"
        file_data = params[:import_file].tempfile.read.encode(utf8_format)
    end
end
```

P.S. Also I try do that with `iconv` but it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start from a known encoding with valid content (and compatible characters for input and output) before you will be able to successfully convert a string.

`ASCII-8BIT` doesn't assign Unicode-compatible characters to values `128..255` - it cannot be converted to Unicode.

The chances are that the input - as you say it is text - is in some other encoding to start with. You could start by assuming `ISO-8859-1` ("Latin-1") which is quite a common encoding, although you may have some other clue, or know what characters to expect in the file, in which case you should try others.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
file_data = params[:import_file].tempfile.read.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')
utf8_file_data = file_data.encode(utf8_format)
```

This probably will not give you an error, but if my guess at 'ISO-8859-1' is wrong, it will give you gibberish unfortunately.